# Angular - получить данные в формате JSON от сервера для использования в том же компоненте

Tags: typescript, angular

Пытаюсь добиться такого поведения:

```
getAuth() {return false;}
currentAuth: Auth = {
    "auth": this.getAuth()
};
```

Но функция getAuth() должна вернуть результат обращения к простому АПИ:

```
{"auth":false}
```

Пытаюсь как то так:

```
getAuth() {   
  this.http.get('/server/api/userService').subscribe(data => {
   this.user = data;
   console.log(this.user.auth); // тут вижу нормальное значение, но на этом мои знания заканчиваются и не могу вернуть это значение из функции для использования ниже, в том же компоненте
  });
}



currentAuth: Auth = {
    "auth": this.getAuth()
};
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HttpClient

- `http.get` - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get
  *там дока*
- пример - https://angular.io/guide/http
  *там куча куча ... кода с вынесением в сервисы и ничего не понятно по делу.*
- `Observable<T>` - https://angular.io/guide/observables
  *там тоже дока*

> **Б**удь внимателен, приведённый код писался в блокнотике на коленке - работоспособность не гарантирую. Но идею донести должен.

### зачем нужен `http.get`

`http.get` нужен для того, чтобы ваш код работал и в вебе и "на мобилке" (native)
*инфа без пруфа, как я её понимаю*

### `http.get` как и `fetch` асинхронен

поэтому давайте для понимания как он работает заменим его на `fetch`.
*мы ведь все знаем как работает fetch*

```
interface $auth {
    auth: any;
}
interface $user extends $auth {
    name: any;
}
class Q {
    user: $user;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.reqUserAuth()
    }
    async reqUserAuth() {
        const r = await fetch('/server/api/userAuth')
        if (!r.ok) {
            const e = new Error('!r.ok')
            console.error(e)
            return;
        }
        const data: $auth = await (r.json() as Promise<$auth>)

        if(!this.user)this.user = {} as any;
        Object.assign(this.user, data)
    }
}
```

```
<div>
{{user?.auth}}
<div>
```

### 0

Этот пример имеет смысл вынести в сервисы, но как и в предыдущем - не обязательно.

```
interface $user {
    auth: any;
}
class Q {
    user: $user;
    _user: Observable<$user> = this.http.get<$user>('/server/api/userService')
    ngOnInit() {
        this._user.subscribe((data: $user) => {
            this.user = data;
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: `http.get нужен для того, чтобы ваш код работал и в вебе и "на мобилке" (native)` > не совсем. `HttpClient` под капотом использует `XMLHttpRequest`, который может отменять запросы. `AbortController` для отмены `fetch` запросов не поддерживается в IE/Safari, а так `fetch` имеет cross-support. Но мне не совсем понятно, зачем в ответ вовсе идет речь про `fetch`, у автора проблемы с пониманием асинхронности, а не с семантикой работы `HttpClient`. Да, и `subscribe` возвращает подписку, а не поток.

Comment: "который может отменять запросы" -  а полифилы в ангуляр проектах вы никода не испольуте? если используете - так давайте подумает почему бы нам не использовать полифил для `fetch` .... так что остаюсь при своём мнении, что это "для мобилок".

Comment: зачем в ответе `fetch` если у автора проблемы с асинхонностью. если автор знает как работает fetch - он всё поймёт. ©мы ведь все знаем как работает fetch

Comment: а тут вы наверное правы: "`subscribe ` возвращает подписку, а не поток." - в лом устанавливать ангуляр и потроха(мой калькулятор виснет от него). отредактировал ответ, посмотрите пж, да и правки никто не запрещал...

Comment: @overthesanity, а если дать свой ответ, так это ещё и поощряется! да-да, я вам говорю, вам автор спасибо скажет, точно-точно, правда сначала минусов накидают : )

Comment: `так давайте подумает почему бы нам не использовать полифил для fetch` > весь жизненный цикл HTTP запросов учитывая перехватчики, сериализация/десериализация завязаны на HttpClient, зачем тянуть какой-то полифил и увеличивать размер бандла, если все уже есть из коробки? В Антихрупкости есть хороший подход - доказывать должны те, кто предлагают что-то новое или нестандартное, а не те, кто следует заведенному или естественному порядку

Comment: `доказывать должны ` 1. уточню. ни в ответе, ни в этой переписке я не призываю использовать `fetch` 2. я лишь высказываю свои мысли 3. я пытаюсь разъяснить почему я так мыслю 4. и тут вы говорите мне что сделал не всё возможное и ещё остался должен.(без вашего желания я безсилен) 5. окончательное, повторюсь: если мы вдруг начнём использовать `fetch` или любую понравившуюся вам библиотеку - ангуляр не сломается! однако, до тек пор, пока вы не решите перенести проект на натив.

Comment: Дело в том, что мы с ангуляром как мартышка и очки, я только делаю робкие попытки понять тайпскрипт. С выводом полученого результата от апи в шаблон проблем нет. А вот как по-простому достать значение от сервера и передать дальше не пойму. Где-то промелькнула мысль, что у меня проблемы с пониманием асинхронности, наверно это так. Может есть какой-то простой способ? Тупо присвоить переменной значение, полученное от сервера и использовать ее ниже по коду в том же компоненте?

Comment: Оба примера у меня не сработали, скорее всего какая-то мелочь, но мелочи для меня самое сложное. В итоге пошел совершенно другим путем, добился цели. Ответ отметил как принятый, может пригодится тем, кто мало-мальски понимает ТС.

Comment: 1)в обоиx примерах почти чистый JS. 2) почитайте про фетч https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch. 3) по умолчанию в ангуляре любое присвоение `this.variable = 'some new data'` ведёт к перерисовке

Comment: > `по умолчанию в ангуляре любое присвоение this.variable = 'some new data' ведёт к перерисовке ` - глупость =))

Comment: Ведь правда? Но это ещё не самое странное, он перерисовывается на каждый и ивент!